# OVH active SSL for domains used for redirection

Tags: https, domains, redirects

I have 2 domains: `domain-a.example` is my main website and `domain-b.example` is a domain used to redirect users to my main website (`domain-a.example`).

On my [ovh dashboard](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/domains/redirect-domain-name/) I set the redirection from `domain-b.example` to `https://domain-a.example and https://www.domain-a.example`

The redirection work perfectly. If I go to `http://domain-b.example` I'm redirected to `https://domain-a.example` but if I call my domain-b with **HTTPS** `https://domain-b.example` it doesn't work because I don't have SSL certificates.

I don't understand how I can get SSL on OVH redirection domains.

Comment: That's to be expected, if someone requests a resource over `HTTPS`, it still requires an SSL for that domain even though it's redirecting to another URL with an SSL. The easiest/cheapest solution is just to add Cloudflare to the first domain, which provides free SSL's, then the redirect should work.

Comment: @dan So I have to make redirection myself and don't use OVH redirection ?

Comment: Once you have an SSL on the domain you're redirecting from, you can do the redirect however you like. Cloudflare also provides redirects using [Page Rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-).